# Why is my raster range changing when converting from one format to another?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, raster-conversion

I am trying to export some rasters from .bil to GRID format and my workflow is as follows. I open up the raster I want to convert and take a screenshot of the raster information under the source tab. I then right click the raster, go down to export and then input all of the same settings except export as GRID. I am also making sure the extent is the same as the original layer, all the rows and columns are the same as well.

NoData value is accounted for, the pyramid levels are the same, and I've tried both nearest neighbor and bilinear with the same thing happening. Any ideas why the range is changing?

[image: Picture of my ranges]

Comment: Did you try comparing these results with raster calculator? Like `r1 - r2` for seeing if raster values changed. Also, if you're exporting the same raster as GRID, why are you using NN or bilinear interpolation?

Comment: There isn't an option to not pick a resample choice